# How can i add hotkey for a group

Tags: shortcut, groups

Selecting a group object is long process. We click and object and shift+G and then a pop arise and then we click on group again. After several click group objects selected Or we go to the out-liner and change from all scenes to group then we select the group.

Any other way or hotkey to add for just if click on a object and press a hotkey it should go all the process and select the group objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select in the Preferences what type of group you want to be selected specifically:

[image: type of group]

Answer (score -1):

You *should* be able to set a custom hotkey for selecting in a group (just right-click the menu item when you pull up the Group selection menu and choose Change Shortcut).

Alternatively, don't forget that you can use numbers on menus like the Group selection menu. In your case, you could use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>→<kbd>7</kbd>, since the Group option is the seventh option in that list.

Comment: When i change the key for example numpad . and when select a object and click the numpad. the pop arise again that i do not need. And for alternative is the same click shift+g and then 7 from keyboard or selecting with the mouse. A shortcut then should select the group object at a click as mention above if i click numpad. means it should select all the group objects. Thanks

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Changing the menu item's hotkey changes the hotkey for the whole menu.